# Why the background shape of the TextView is clipped and how to solve it?

Tags: android

I am implementing a chat activity using RecyclerView. Each item is inflated with the layout file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="11dp"
    android:paddingBottom="11dp"
    android:gravity="right|bottom">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
        android:maxWidth="219dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="This is a message"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_circle_right"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_circle_right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The background drawable is a rectangle with corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/color_chat_bubble_right"/>
</shape>
```

But the preview in Android Studio show that the background is clipped at the top. I've deployed the app onto my android phone but the problem is still there. What's wrong with my code?

The preview is shown below:

[image: render screenshot]

Comment: What will happen if you  change `android:gravity="right|bottom` to `top` gravity

Comment: @Jedil The problem disappears. So strange! However I have to set the gravity to `right|bottom`...Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"` if parent container gravity is bottom.

Remove `layout_marginBottom` or change parent gravity to top `android:gravity="right|top"`

Comment: But I have to make the TextView and the other two dots aligning at the bottom, so how can I implement it?